# Count the loan cycle based on condition

Tags: plsql, psql, plsqldeveloper

Ok, im currently writing a report to count how many times a client got a loan.
for example if the client has got only one loan record i need to show 1 and null for his the previous loan record since it is his first loan record.
but if the client got more then one record for example if i sum all his loan record i get 4 records and his previous record should be 3

something like this

| cycle | p_cycle |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

I have tried this and it works fine but only for the clients that has already closed their previous loan account or doesn't have parallel current loans (> 2 loan at the same time)
in case if the client has > 2 parallel ongoing loans my script returns me something like this

| cycle | p_cycle |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |

```
SELECT p_acct.cod_cust_id,
                         COUNT(p_acct.cod_cust_id) p_cycle
                    FROM acct_dtls c_acct,
                         acct_dtls p_acct
                   WHERE c_acct.cod_cust_id = p_acct.cod_cust_id
                     AND p_acct.dat_first_disb IS NOT NULL
                     AND c_acct.dat_first_disb IS NOT NULL
                     AND p_acct.dat_last_mnt =
                         (SELECT MAX(dd.dat_last_mnt)
                            FROM acct_dtls dd
                           WHERE dd.dat_first_disb IS NOT NULL
                             AND c_acct.cod_cust_id = dd.cod_cust_id
                             AND dd.dat_acct_open < c_acct.dat_acct_open)
                   GROUP BY p_acct.cod_cust_id
```

Im thinking if there any way to use union all to achieve the result that i want or any other way.

Comment: So, with a just a select and results.... are we supposed to guess the data structure and the actual data  that is in your tables ? With sample data (create table statements and insert statements - no screenshots), someone could try and reproduce the issue and find a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

As there  is no sample data all we could do is to try to guess the basic elements of data structure and give you some guidence to the expected result. Here are two dummy tables and sql code resulting as you asked (with some extra data). There are no conditions here but you can filter the resulting dataset or adjust the Case expressions to get what you want.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a : 
    acct (CUST_ID, CUST_ACCOUNT, CUST_NAME) AS 
        (   Select 101, '11111', 'John' From Dual Union All
            Select 102, '22222', 'Jane' From Dual Union All
            Select 103, '33333', 'Mike' From Dual Union All
            Select 104, '44444', 'Boby' From Dual
        ),
    acct_dtls (CUST_ID, LOAN_ID, AMOUNT, START_DATE, END_DATE) AS
        (   Select 101, 1011, 1000, To_Date('01.01.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  To_Date('31.12.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 1021, 2000, To_Date('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  To_Date('31.12.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 1022, 160, To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  To_Date('31.07.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1031, 3000, To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  To_Date('31.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1032, 2000, To_Date('01.06.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  Null From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1033, 1000, To_Date('01.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  Null From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n   S Q L :
Select      a.CUST_ID, a.CUST_ACCOUNT, a.CUST_NAME,
            Nvl(Count(ad.LOAN_ID), 0) "TOT_LOANS",
            Case When Nvl(Count(ad.LOAN_ID), 0) = 0 Then 0 Else Nvl(Count(ad.LOAN_ID), 0) - 1 End "PREV_LOANS",
          --
            Min(ad.START_DATE) "FIRST_START_DATE", 
            Max(ad.END_DATE) "LAST_END_DATE",
            Count(Case When ad.START_DATE Is Not Null And ad.END_DATE Is Null Then 1 End) "PENDING_LOANS",
            Count(Case When ad.START_DATE Is Not Null And ad.END_DATE Is Not Null Then 1 End) "CLOSED_LOANS"
From            acct a
Left Join   acct_dtls ad ON(ad.CUST_ID = a.CUST_ID)
Group By    a.CUST_ID, a.CUST_ACCOUNT, a.CUST_NAME
Order By    a.CUST_ID, a.CUST_ACCOUNT, a.CUST_NAME

/*    R e s u l t :
   CUST_ID CUST_ACCOUNT CUST_NAME   TOT_LOANS PREV_LOANS FIRST_START_DATE LAST_END_DATE PENDING_LOANS CLOSED_LOANS
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- --------- ----------------- ------------- ------------- ------------
       101        11111 John                1         0 01-JAN-21         31-DEC-21                 0            1
       102        22222 Jane                2         1 01-JAN-20         31-JUL-23                 0            2
       103        33333 Mike                3         2 01-JAN-23         31-OCT-23                 2            1
       104        44444 Boby                0         0                                             0            0  */
```